# How to create a nodejs module to which I can pass an argument?

Tags: node.js

I'd like to create a data access object where I can pass a database name, say:

```
var Dao = require('./dao')

mydb = new Dao('sample_database');
mydb.append('hello')
```

any idea how to do this? thanks

Comment: you can use env var and access it by `process.env`

Comment: Can you add more detailed about what are you trying to do?

Comment: What does `dao.js` look like? And what are you trying to accomplish (expected result/output)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created minimal solution from what I understand.

**doa.js**

```
let Dao = function(dbName) {
    console.log(dbName);
}

Dao.prototype.append = function (text) {
  console.log("append " + text)
}
module.exports = Dao;´
```

**main.js**

```
let Dao = require('./dao');
let daoInstance = new Dao('testName');
daoInstance.append("apple");
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Once you have the basics then move on to the various design patterns javascript can handle. https://www.google.com/amp/s/scotch.io/amp/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know

Comment: This example is correct. @AngeloC, Before use a function from a another js file you have to export the function and catch it from the file you going to use it.